# efficient way of finding all unfiltered vertices of a filtered graph, in graph-tool library?

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

I'm using graph-tool for analyzing disease spread models on a graph.
I want to have a filtered graph which only consists of the infected vertices, the vertices which are going to infect their neighbors.

the problem is that when I filter the infected vertices, the rest of the data is missing, I am aware of GraphView subclass, but the problem is that having the original graph stored somewhere doesn't help me when I'm iterating on the edges of the filtered graph, since I don't have access the the equivalent of the vertex, and can't infect it's neighbors. (change their properties.)

is there an efficient way to help my task?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have access to the vertices of the original graph, by using the `Graph.vertex()` method.

Say if `g` is your original graph and `u` is the filtered one, you can do:

```
for e in u.edges():
    v = e.source()
    v_orig = g.vertex(v)             # corresponding vertex in unfiltered graph
    for w in v_orig.out_neighbors():
        print(w)                     # neighbors in the unfiltered graph
```